# Пересылка почты от двух доменов через внешний SMTP сервер

Tags: email, postfix

Смысл задачи такой.

Есть к примеру **2** домена, **domain1.com** **domain2.com**

Нужно более простым способом, на сервере к которому они привязаны, реализовать пересылку почты (relay) через внешний SMTP сервер.

То есть, чтобы вся почта с этих доменов, к примеру попадала в какой-то один ящик на майл.ру или другого провайдера.

Кто сталкивался, обьясните пожалуйста подробно логику реализации/работы этой задачи.